# Adding custom fonts in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am just starting out with HTML, CSS and co. and for the last hour or so I've tried implementing a custom font to my project. I've tried everything, creating a fonts folder or putting the font files in the same directory as my index.html file, but nothing is working!

I am grateful for every help, solving this problem! :)

[my directory and css code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj5Vy.png)

```
    font-family: league_spartanregular;
    src: url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.svg#league_spartanregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body{
    background-color: #f4f4f4
}

#main-header{

text-align: center;
font-family: league_spartanregular;
font-size: 80px;
}

p{
    font-family: league_spartanregular;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep fonts in /fonts folder, this will help with clean structure of site down the line. Remember - everything what's in the file is relative to that file - meaning, if you'd put these fonts in `/css` folder - it would work.

If you want to go back in folder structure just use `../`. It's useful if you want to store images for example in `/img` and not in `/css/img`.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: league_spartanregular;
    src: url('../fonts/leaguespartan-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/leaguespartan-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/leaguespartan-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/leaguespartan-bold-webfont.svg#league_spartanregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out Google Fonts! :)
simply search for your font and upon clicking one, there will be a tab at the bottom. Click on that and there will be a link which you can include in your HTML above your stylesheet link.
https://fonts.google.com/

I'm also somewhat new here so apologies if my answer isn't satisfactory.
Cheers :)

Comment: Yea, I already tried it and it worked, but I wanted to be able to work with every possibility. Thanks nonetheless!!!

Answer (score 0):

If this css is from a .css file in the `css/` folder, you'll need to add `../` to your filepaths, eg:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: league_spartanregular;
    src: url('../leaguespartan-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../leaguespartan-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../leaguespartan-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../leaguespartan-bold-webfont.svg#league_spartanregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Otherwise, if you open the inspector in your browser, you should able to see the errors associated with it trying (and failing) to find these files with red 404 messages.

Answer (score 0):

first go to google.fonts select one fonts,there you finds two things one is link in  tag which you put in  tag of your html file and second thing is font-family of CSS which you use in your css file
  [here is google font links](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Roboto)

[image: this is a snippet which give you some idea how to select]